# Show multiple rows from single row data based on column values

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a data below

```
ID         DATE     COMPLIANCE ISBREAKREDUCED ISSECONDMEALBREAKREDUCED
1208240    4/12/2015    2              1                1
```

How do I use it in my base query to show different rows for column ISBREAKREDUCED & ISSECONDMEALBREAKREDUCED if there values are 1.
This table join condition is based on id and date fields which is why it selects single row. How can I split this row into a multiple rows in the output?

Comment: The desired output is not clear. Do you want to unpivot? Or, do you want to have only single column but 2 rows? Please edit your question and add your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a typical **UNPIVOT** query.

You could do it as:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 1208240 ID, 1 ISBREAKREDUCED, 1 ISSECONDMEALBREAKREDUCED FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 1208241 ID, 2 ISBREAKREDUCED, 3 ISSECONDMEALBREAKREDUCED FROM dual
  4  )
  5  SELECT *
  6  FROM
  7    (SELECT                                                         *
  8    FROM DATA UNPIVOT (ISSECONDMEALBREAKREDUCED FOR ISBREAKREDUCED IN (ISBREAKREDUCED AS 1, ISSECONDMEALBREAKREDUCED AS 1))
  9    )
 10  WHERE ISBREAKREDUCED         =1
 11  AND ISSECONDMEALBREAKREDUCED =1
 12  /

        ID ISBREAKREDUCED ISSECONDMEALBREAKREDUCED
---------- -------------- ------------------------
   1208240              1                        1
   1208240              1                        1

SQL>
```